# Cosmos Trigger not triggering

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have created cosmosdb and azure function 1.0 using visual studio. I have added cosmosdb connectionstring and storageaccount key in local.settings.json  While adding or modifying in cosmos my azure function is not triggering.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "cdb",
            collectionName: "myc",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "DBConnection",
    LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]IReadOnlyList<Document> input,
TraceWriter log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
                log.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].Id);
            }
        }


{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "Storage account key",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "Storage account key",
    "DBConnection": "Cosmos db connection string"
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us your function and config with sensitive information redacted

Comment: Is `IReadOnlyList input` a valid parameter for the change feed? What if you used `IReadOnlyList<Document> input`? We use `JArray` as the input but `IReadOnlyList` with no Type doesn't look like it would work?

Comment: While creating cosmos trigger azure function it comes as default IReadOnlyList.

Comment: `IReadOnlyList<T>` requires a type implementation. `IReadOnlyList input` is not an acceptable parameter

Comment: It needs to be `IReadOnlyList<Document>`

Comment: @MarkC. so that why its not triggering? can you suggest which one i have to use?

Comment: Look at my first comment

Comment: could you tell me which nuget package i have to use for JArray?

Comment: Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-changefeed-functions, there are common reasons for the Trigger not to fire

Comment: I am getting this error :  Function1: The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client: Service is currently unavailable.

Comment: I have a feeling that it's gonna be something related to your `DBConnection`. Is it in this format? `AccountEndpoint=https://accountname.documents.azure.com:443/‌​;AccountKey=yourkey==`

Comment: Are you connecting to the Emulator? Or a real account?

Comment: @NickChapsas  Yes same AccountEndpoint=https://x.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=***;

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta while creating azure function from storage account i selected none, not the storage emulator

Comment: Wait so what does this value look like: `AzureWebJobsStorage` ?

Comment: @NickChapsas  Its like DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=my;AccountKey=mykey;EndpointSuffix=x

Comment: In order to run Azure Functions you either need a real Azure Storage account (with a real Connection String), or, when running locally, the Azure Storage Emulator, which has a connection string of `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`